# Django dumpdata: "Unable to serialize database" error due to a BitFlagField var

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization

I've been trying to create a fixture of a table, but it's always been failing with the following message: `CommandError: Unable to serialize database: __str__ returned non-string (type method)`. The stacktrace was equally unhelpful, pointing to one of the Django files as the culprit.

After some fiddling about, I've managed to pinpoint the culprit in the models.py:

```
class UserExtra(model.Models):
(...)
blocked = BitFlagField(
    flags=(
        'manual', 'system', 'tries', 'expired', 'inactivity',
        'nosys_nobypass'
    ),
    db_column='ind_block'
)
```

The class is only a list of vars and lacks any sort of function. If I remove that var and run the dumpdata command, it works. How do I serialize this field?

Comment: Where does `BitFlagField` come from, a package or is your own custom field?

Comment: `from .db import Model, AutoDateTimeField, BitFlagField` ; this db being "db.py" file in the same directory. BitFlagField is a custom class defined there. While this class doesn't have any `__str__` or serializer function, there is a separate `BitFlagSerializer` class under it.

Comment: Can you share the code for the field?

Comment: Here's the code pertaining to that BitFlagField type - https://pastebin.com/UBPxVcTh

Comment: Did you recently upgrade the version of Django you are running? The error message you are getting is due to your `__str__` methods returning `self.__repr__` which is a method, you are not calling it

Comment: There was an upgrade from version 2.1 to 3.2 that happened around February. I suppose the jump from 2 to 3 changed what Django expects in these custom classes' `__str__` functions?

Comment: Returning `self.__repr__` from the `__str__` method has never been valid, it's surprising that it ever worked. Maybe the method never used to be called?

Comment: Changing the `__str__` 's return to `str(self.value)` makes the dumpdata command work, though loading it back is failing since the value is being saved as a string in the JSON file, which then causes a DeserializationError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ian Shelvington helped me figure out in the comments above, the BitFlagField is a custom made type and the problem was in its `__str__` function's return, as it was calling the `__repr__` method in a wrong manner (`return self.__repr__`).

Closing this because the problem of the original question was solved, though this led to another problem.